# Cannot receive uploaded file in controller - Spring

Tags: java, spring, file-upload

I want to upload .txt file, and process in my controller.
Here is my .jsp file with my form:

```
        <form id="uploadForm" action="contact/importContacts" method="POST"
            enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file" />
            <button id="upload" class="pull-right btn btn-raised btn-primary" type="submit">Upload</button>
        </form>
```

And this is the controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/contact")
public class ContactController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/importContacts")
    @ResponseBody
    public String importContacts(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

        if(file != null) {
            return "OK";
        } else {
            return "NULL";
        }
    }
}
```

The page is going on /myPage/contact/importContacts, but not in contoller. I put breakpoint on controller, but the app don't stop there. Any solution?

Btw I followed this [tut](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly add the `RequestMethod`

`@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/importContacts")`

Comment: Noting happens again. Also if I delete importContacts, the app still go to /myPage/contact/importContacts....

Comment: Then maybe provide more code. E.g. `Application` class, configuration files etc.